# Adding a column in a dataframe with the given property

Tags: python

I have the following dataframe,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [[5.4, 15.3],[2.0,9.1]],'b':[[9.8,2.0],[9.7,6.0,1.2]]})
```

I want to add a column 'c' using assign function such that each element in 'c' is a list of elements we get after doubling up the elements of corresponding list in 'a'.
I wrote the below code'

```
df.assign(c=np.array(df['a'])*2)
```

But it gave the wrong output.
I'm expecting the output as shown below:

```
        a                 b            c             
0  [5.4, 15.3]       [9.8, 2.0]   [10.8, 30.6]
1   [2.0, 9.1]  [9.7, 6.0, 1.2]   [4.0, 18.2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there you can utilize list comprehension to create a new list and assign to df['c'] as follows;

```
df['c'] = [np.array(x)*2 for x in df['a'].to_list()]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is really easy to add new column

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[1,1,1]})
df['c'] = [5,5,5]
print(df)
```

Comment: This adds a column, yes, but it doesn't address what the OP is asking for, which is how to make pretty specific new column based off a specific existing column.